# Issue drawing a Phaser pie graphic

Tags: javascript, html, phaser-framework

I'm trying to create a pie chart with Phaser, using `graphics` to draw each slice of the pie (`graphics.arc(...)`). The problem is that when it renders I get (what I think) an unexpected result.

I basically want to draw 3 slices the same size, the code I use looks something like this:

```
function degToRad(degrees) {
  return (degrees * Math.PI)/180;
}

var total = 3;
var width = 300;

for (var i = 0; i < total; i++) {
  var radius = Math.floor(width / 2);
  var deg = 360 / total;
  var start = degToRad(i * deg);
  var end = degToRad((i + 1) * deg);

  graphics = game.add.graphics()
  graphics.beginFill(0xFF0000)
  graphics.lineStyle(2, 0x000000)
  graphics.moveTo(0, 0);
  graphics.arc(0, 0, radius, start, end, false);
  graphics.endFill()
}
```

I've created 3 fiddles to show the difference between a canvas, pixi and phaser based examples, each of them using the same process to draw the slices:

canvas: https://jsfiddle.net/oL414v9t/1/

pixi: http://jsfiddle.net/ngma7snq/59/

phaser: https://jsfiddle.net/1ck39fos/1/

Does anyone know why this happens and how can I achieve what I want?

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that there is some sort of bug in the `arc` function in `Graphics.js`. You can draw the arc clockwise or anti-clockwise, but if you choose clockwise (like in your code example) then it looks like it doesn't return to the center of the arc, [see code here](https://github.com/photonstorm/phaser-ce/blob/7926fe66129088b8a4b7d20ec9eb51fab9eeb9b3/src/gameobjects/Graphics.js#L699).

If you change your code so that it draws the segments in a counter-clockwise order then it works. You have to set the last parameter of `arc` to true instead of false, and change some more stuff around. See code below, that seems to work.

```
function create() {
  var total = 3;
  var colors = [0xFF0000, 0x00FF00, 0x0000FF, 0xFFFF00, 0xFF00FF, 0x00FFFF];

  for (var i = 0; i < total; i++) {
    var centerX = Math.floor(width / 2);
    var centerY = Math.floor(height / 2);
    var radius = Math.floor(width / 2);

    var deg = 360 / total;
    var start = degreesToRadians(total-i * deg);
    var end = degreesToRadians((total-i - 1) * deg);

    graphics = game.add.graphics();
    graphics.beginFill(colors[i]);
    graphics.lineStyle(2, 0x000000);
    graphics.moveTo(centerX, centerY);
    graphics.arc(centerX, centerY, radius, start, end, true);
    graphics.endFill()
    game.stage.addChild(graphics);
  }
}
```